# gcloud pubsub : How to send xml payload to local GCF pubsub using curl?

Tags: curl, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-messaging

How do I send an xml payload to local GCF? Should I change something in any config to make it accept as text/xmo?

Would be great if I don't need to bother about converting that xml to base64 etc.

```sh
curl -vX POST http://localhost:8080 -H "Content-Type: text/json" -d @testmsg.json
```

testmsg.json

```json
{
  "context": {
    "eventId":"1144231683168617",
    "timestamp":"2020-05-06T07:33:34.556Z",
    "eventType":"google.pubsub.topic.publish",
    "resource":{
      "service":"pubsub.googleapis.com",
      "name":"projects/sample-project/topics/gcf-test",
      "type":"type.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage"
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage",
    "attributes": {
    "attr1":"attr1-value"
    },
    "data": "@../ord/myorder.xml"
  }
}
```

A simple function (ignore class name error)
[image]

Comment: Did you finally solve this issue? May it have something to do with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210592/gcp-pubsub-publish-message-via-curl-type-of-request

Comment: No & No. For both questions.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the content type? `--header "Content-Type: application/xml"`. Perhaps I don't understand your question, but you want to send an xml and are specifying a json. Why?