# Is a GCP access token valid for as long as the corresponding service account is?

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iam

I would like to publish events to a PubSub topic using REST request directly from my Java app. I understand that the correct way is to use Google APIs for that, like PubSubTemplate in Spring ... However, we are trying to avoid adding GCP-related dependencies to our application as it is old and there will be tons of conflicts.

So, I verified I can publish a base64-encoded event to PubSub using approach outlined here: [GCP PubSub: Publish message via CURL type of request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210592/gcp-pubsub-publish-message-via-curl-type-of-request) using this CURL command:

```
curl -H 'content-type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST --data $'{  "messages": [{"data": "abcd"}]}'  https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT/topics/$TOPIC:publish
```

and using Access Token produced by this command:

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

Now I would like to do this from my Java Spring app, using RestTemplate and, hopefully, by using a property with the value of the access token generated by Jenkins at the deploy time for a specified service account.

My main question is: will the generated token be valid for the duration of the service account life? or will it keep expiring? and if it is the later - what are the options to refresh it?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Commands `gcloud auth login` with [`gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token) inserts [Application Default Credentials (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable), which don't seem to be [short-lived access credentials](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-direct#sa-credentials-oauth), that would feature a `lifetime` value.

See [Spring Cloud GCP](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gcp); also see [`spring-tips/bootiful-gcp`](https://github.com/spring-tips/bootiful-gcp); there's no need to reinvent the wheel with `RestTemplate`; it's abstracted:
[`org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.M3/reference/html/_spring_cloud_gcp_for_pub_sub.html).

---

In Spring the preferred method to declare service account credentials is to set a property:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:/usr/local/key.json
```

As the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.M3/reference/html/spring-cloud-gcp-core.html#_credentials) states, it falls back to `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` (current user) or `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, when the properties value cannot be determined.

Comment: thanks, Martin. Yes, I understand the correct way to do this is by using the GCP client libs / APIs, with the corresponding use of credentials . My desire was not to go that way , to avoid adding any gcp-related dependencies into my pom, but to stick with plain HTTP request - like in curl - with just substituted values for token and gcp project_id/topic . I guess what you are saying is that this is not going to work - which was my gut feeling too :) Thank you for the response!